# If $A$ is an anti-symmetric matrix of size $N$ where $N$ is odd, then $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **True or False:** If $A$ is an anti-symmetric matrix of size $N$ where $N$ is odd then $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Through observation, it is false. However, how can I prove that this statement is false?

What part of the definition of an anti-symmetric matrix would allow me to do this?

This is for freshman linear algebra.

Comment: Why do you say "Through observation, it is false"?  Do you have an example to share?

Comment: To prove this is false, it would be sufficient for you to present a particular $N\times N$ matrix where $N$ is odd (e.g. a particular $3\times 3$ matrix) that is anti symmetric and does not have $0$ as an eigenvalue. (You would need to show that it does not have $0$ as an eigenvalue.) *(This is due to the general principle that to show that something is not always true, a specific counterexample is sufficient.)* But do you have such a matrix?

Comment: To prove a universal statement is false, it suffices to produce a single instance of it failing, as Minus One-Twelfth says. But I think that you are incorrect in your observations... Because note that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $A$ is not invertible, if and only if its determinant is $0$. And in general, the determinant of a matrix $M$ and of its transpose $M^t$ are equal... So....

Answer (score 4):

The statement is true, you only need to prove that $\det A=0$.

$\det A=\det (A^T)=\det (-A)=(-1)^N\det A=-\det A$, then $\det A$ has to be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is ***true*** for *real* skew-symmetric matrices $A = -A^T$ of odd size $N$.

Since

$\text{size} A = N \; \text{odd}, \tag 1$

the characteristic polynomial

$\det(A - \lambda I) \in \Bbb R[\lambda], \tag 2$

which satisfies

$\deg(\det(A - \lambda I)) = N \tag 3$

has at least one real root; thus our proof will be completed if we show that the only real eigenvalue of a skew-symmetric matrix is $0$; now if

$A v = \lambda v, \tag 4$

we have

$\lambda \langle v, v \rangle = \langle v, \lambda v \rangle =\langle v, Av \rangle = \langle A^T v, v \rangle = \langle -Av, v \rangle = \langle -\lambda v, v \rangle = -\lambda \langle v, v \rangle; \tag 5$

with $v \ne 0$, $\langle v, v \rangle \ne 0$, whence

$\lambda = -\lambda \Longrightarrow \lambda = 0. \tag 6$

$OE\Delta$.